# Twitter Bootstrap -  Hide Column then Center Column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap Responsive - HTML appears like...

```
<div class="row-fluid Center">
    <div id="divMapCanvas" class="span6">
        <div id="map_canvas">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="divMapPanel" class="span6">
        <div id="map_panel">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Test Webpage: http://gfw.yyyz.net/Contact

What I would like to do is initially hide the divMapPanel `div` and have the divMapCanvas `div` centered on the page. Then after the directions button is pressed, the divMapCanvas would move to the left and the divMapPanel would appear. I have tried merely hiding the divMapPanel, but I can't get the divMapCanval centered.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the the div with class `span6` that wrap your canvas, you need to set a fixed width (I used `width: 526px;` when I got it to work on your example page, but you could use % instead, or what have you, but it cannot be set to auto which is the default setting), you also have to get rid of the floating by adding `float: none;` and `margin: 0 auto;`.

On the `divMapPanel` you need to add `display: none`, to make sure that it doesn't take up any space in the DOM. Using `visibility: hidden` for instance will not work.

Then when the user click on direction and you want to display both elements side by side, you get rid of these settings by adding `float: left` etc. back in, and both elements should appear side by side.